# how to fix : validator is undefined in magento 2 checkout page

Tags: javascript, magento

In magento 2 checkout page: an error was caught, please see the log as belows:

Uncaught TypeError: validator is undefined
validateEmail https://www.productcategory.com/static/version1679504321/frontend/Gd/base/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email.js:166

```
emailHasChanged https://www.productcategory.com/static/version1679504321/frontend/Gd/base/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email.js:90

setNested https://www.productcategory.com/static/version1679504321/frontend/Gd/base/en_US/mage/utils/objects.js:44

nested https://www.productcategory.com/static/version1679504321/frontend/Gd/base/en_US/mage/utils/objects.js:118

set https://www.productcategory.com/static/version1679504321/frontend/Gd/base/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element.js:305

updateValue https://www.productcategory.com/static/version1679504321/frontend/Gd/base/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/links.js:80

notifySubscribers https://www.productcategory.com/static/version1679504321/frontend/Gd/base/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1320
```

Refresh the checkout page can resolve this issue, what is the reason to cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

finally found this issue is introduced by amazon modules, remove them can resolve this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).